# CodeIgniter Securing Views

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller that checks if a certain user may access some view , and loads the view if he may . Do I need to be worried about whether that view is secured or not ? What I mean is , is the only way for a user to see that view is by going through the controller or are there ways to see it by playing with the url , e.g : mysite/somedir/forbiddenview.php

I guess the same goes for other resources - what can be viewed publicly (other than the controllers of course..)

Comment: are your viewfiles in a folder that is publicly available? If so, you can use a .htaccess file in your views folder and add `deny from all` in there to block direct access. If users can get to your viewfile when fiddeling with the url depend on how your code is set-up.

Comment: I'm using the default CI setup , so they are in application/views/

Comment: Amplifying John's comment - it's a good practice to move your application folder and system folder outside of your public folder. YOu need to set a couple of paths in index.php, but after that you can feel much better about controlling access.

Answer (score 0):

Generally everything in codeigniter gets routed, and that begins with the index.php file which is public. Things in the application directory are not accessible directly by URL by default, and are safe as long as you have good security measures in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

This pretty much from the guide itself [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/appflow.html)

Checking right access level in the controller is a good practice, and it's even better to check it **My_Controller** if you have middle controller

On the other hand accessing view folder directly is almost impossible due to index.html file there

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Directory access is forbidden.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

and you should use the same **index.html** file in your website resource e.i. uploads, CSS, Javascript, images, ...etc.